# Add "checked" to radio button on load with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Based on Bootstrap 5's dark mode switch javascript (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#javascript) I'm trying to set a radio button to "checked" on page load, as well as when the colour mode is changed.

Using the following javascript:

```
    <script>
      (() => {
        'use strict'

        const getStoredTheme = () => localStorage.getItem('theme')
        const setStoredTheme = theme => localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)

        const getPreferredTheme = () => {
          const storedTheme = getStoredTheme()
          if (storedTheme) {
            return storedTheme
          }

          return window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'light'
        }

        const setTheme = theme => {
          if (theme === 'auto' && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', 'dark')
          } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', theme)
          }
        }

        setTheme(getPreferredTheme())

        const showActiveTheme = (theme, focus = false) => {
          const themeSwitcher = document.querySelector('#bd-theme')

          if (!themeSwitcher) {
            return
          }

          const btnToActive = document.querySelector(`[data-bs-theme-value="${theme}"]`)

          document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]').forEach(element => {
            element.classList.remove('checked')
          })

          btnToActive.classList.add('checked')

          if (focus) {
            themeSwitcher.focus()
          }
        }

        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', () => {
          const storedTheme = getStoredTheme()
          if (storedTheme !== 'light' && storedTheme !== 'dark') {
            setTheme(getPreferredTheme())
          }
        })

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
          showActiveTheme(getPreferredTheme())

          document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]')
            .forEach(toggle => {
              toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const theme = toggle.getAttribute('data-bs-theme-value')
                setStoredTheme(theme)
                setTheme(theme)
                showActiveTheme(theme, true)
              })
            })
        })
      })()
    </script>
```

I'm trying to control the button group:

```
  <div class="btn-group" id="bd-theme" role="group">
    <input autocomplete="off" checked class="btn-check" data-bs-theme-value="light" id="btnradio1" name="btnradio" type="radio">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-dark" for="btnradio1">
      Light
    </label>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="btn-check" data-bs-theme-value="dark" id="btnradio2" name="btnradio" type="radio">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-dark" for="btnradio2">
      Dark
    </label>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="btn-check" data-bs-theme-value="auto" id="btnradio3" name="btnradio" type="radio">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-dark" for="btnradio3">
      Auto
    </label>
  </div>
```

By default, 'Light' mode is "checked", but if a different 'theme' is already stored then that other radio button should be "checked" instead.

I think the code that needs changing in particular is:

```
        const showActiveTheme = (theme, focus = false) => {
          const themeSwitcher = document.querySelector('#bd-theme')

          if (!themeSwitcher) {
            return
          }

          const btnToActive = document.querySelector(`[data-bs-theme-value="${theme}"]`)

          document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]').forEach(element => {
            element.classList.remove('checked')
          })

          btnToActive.classList.add('checked')

          if (focus) {
            themeSwitcher.focus()
          }
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks like it's already setting the checked value for the selected theme (in the line `btnToActive.classList.add('checked')`).     You just need to call  showActiveTheme on page load, passing it the current theme retrieved from local storage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DanielBeck. That snippet of code seems to add "checked" to the 'class' attribute as a new value, instead of as a new attribute, such as `<input autocomplete="off" checked class="btn-check" ...`.

Comment: ah shoot you're absolutely right, my mistake!  I saw the word "checked" and glossed over the rest :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's `classList` you want to toggle?  It seems like `checked` is just the checked property on the DOMNode that you care about?  Meaning, you just need to set `element.checked = true`, not `element.classList.add('checked')`

```js
document.getElementById('makeDark').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('dark').checked = true;
});

document.getElementById('makeDarkBroken').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('dark').classList.toggle('checked');
});
```

```css
.checked {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label><input id="light" name="demo" value="light" type="radio" checked /> Light</label>
<label><input id="dark" name="demo" value="dark" type="radio" /> Dark</label>

<button id="makeDark">Make Dark</button>
<button id="makeDarkBroken">Make Dark Broken</button>
```

Comment: Perfect - that seems to have fixed it! Thanks for your help, @dave. The only question I do have is, when clicking 'Light' or 'Dark', should I see the "checked" input property change in the source code when inspecting a webpage?

Comment: You wouldn't, if you want to see it when you do inspect element or whatever (but it won't really affect anything - the `.checked` property is what the browser "cares" about), then add `document.getElementById('dark').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');` and `document.getElementById('dark').removeAttribute('checked');`